# How to return an IHttpActionResult inside an MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm tinkering with an MVC `Controller`, having lifted some code out of an `ApiController`:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        var success = await _accountClient.Login(model);
        if (!success)
        {
            return new UnauthorizedResult(Enumerable.Empty<AuthenticationHeaderValue>(), new HttpRequestMessage());
        }
        return new OkResult(new HttpRequestMessage());
    }
}
```

This just doesn't look or feel right, particularly the part where I'm creating a new `HttpRequestMessage`; I'm pretty sure that should somehow come from the incoming `Request`, but I can't figure out where that's supposed to come from.

Also, how do you create the `IEnumerable<AuthenticationHeaderValue>` object for the `challenges` parameter to the `UnauthorizedResult` constructor?

Comment: How about returning `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)` and `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Ok)` and changing your definition as `public async Task<HttpStatusCodeResult> Login(LoginModel model)`?

Comment: @Dandy Ok, well there's another wrinkle in that.  For the `Ok` path, I want to return a token in the header, for which I'm using a custom `OkResultWithToken` that inherits `OkResult` and overrides `ExecuteAsync` and writes the token to the header. Can I do that with an `HttpStatusCodeResult`?

Comment: I am not sure about this, but you can add headers to your response object as `Response.AddHeader("Token","your-generated-token");` and then return the `HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Ok)`.

Comment: @Dandy Thanks, this worked for me.  Want to post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add headers to your `Response` object as

`Response.AddHeader("Token","your-generated-token");`

Also you can change your action method as

```
public async Task<HttpStatusCodeResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    var success = await _accountClient.Login(model);
    if (!success)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Ok);
}
```